# Use Pandas to replace a specific value in a sentence

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I want to replace only specific values in  the 'content' column of Articles.xlsx with values from Column 'Description' of 'macros.xlsx' based on matching values in  column content and  ID in  Column ID of marcros.xlsx.

Articles

| Article ID | Content_Text |
| --- | --- |
| Article 22 | 123 will begin working on January 1. |
| Article 23 | 345 will begin working on January 15 with 678 |

Macros

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | John |
| 345 | Marshall |
| 678 | Wendy |

I tried using the syntax below expecting to see something like this:

Updated Articles

Articles

| Article ID | Content_Text |
| --- | --- |
| Article 22 | John will begin working on January 1. |
| Article 23 | Marshall will begin working on January 15 with Wendy |

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the large 
df_large = pd.read_excel('Articles.xlsx')

# Read the small
df_small = pd.read_excel('macros.xlsx')

# Create a dictionary mapping values from the small spreadsheet to their corresponding replacement values
replacement_dict = dict(zip(df_small['ID'], df_small['Description']))

# Update values in Column H of the large spreadsheet using the map function
df_large['content_text'] = df_large['content_text'].map(lambda x: replacement_dict.get(x, x))

# Save the updated large spreadsheet
df_large.to_excel('updated_Articles.xlsx', index=False)
```

Instead, I'm just getting the original data on the table of Articles with no changes at all. Some of the Content Text may be a long paragraph with multiple values from the ID column as well but none of them seem to have changed.

Comment: Please also include data for reproducibility .

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
import re

s = df_small.astype({'ID': str}).set_index('ID')['Description']

pattern = r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(s.index)
# '\\b(123|345|678)\\b'

df_large['Content_Text'] = (df_large['Content_Text']
                            .str.replace(pattern,
                                         lambda m: s.get(m.group(0)),
                                         regex=True)
                           )
```

*Note that any number matching the ID will also be replaced!*

Output:

```
   Article ID                                          Content_Text
0  Article 22                 John will begin working on January 1.
1  Article 23  Marshall will begin working on January 15 with Wendy
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for most of the rows but many come up blank when there are multiple values from ID in the macros spreadsheet in a cell.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a dictionary and use replace:

```
df_large.assign(
    Content_Text = df_large['Content_Text'].replace(
        dict(df_small.astype(str).assign(ID = lambda x: r'\b' + x['ID'] + r'\b').to_records(index = False)
        ),regex=True))
```

Output:

```
   Article ID                                       Content_Text
0  Article 22              John will begin working on January 1.
1  Article 23  Marshall will begin working on January 15 with Wendy
```

Comment: Just one remark about using `replace` with a dictionary, this will read again the string for each key:value ;)

Comment: ahh, so does this mean there will be a performance issue on a larger dataset?

Comment: It depends how many items are in the small dataframe, but yes it's like chaining `replace` for python strings. The regex approach is not without issues either but is generally faster than repeated `replace` and if you really have a lot of keys you can optimize the regex with a trie. In the end your have to test it on the real data.